# nodejs handlebars: 'TypeError: this.engine is not a function'

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, render

I try to use handlebars template in Express. I get this Error-Message:

> TypeError: this.engine is not a function
>       at View.render (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:128:8) ...

with this code:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var expressHandlebars  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', expressHandlebars({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static('views'));

app.route('/single/:id')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.render(process.cwd() + `/public/single-poll`, {
            id: req.params.id
        });
    });

app.listen(process.env.PORT,  function () {
    console.log('Node.js listening on port ' + process.env.PORT + '...');
});
```

When I replace the render() function with sendFile() is works fine. I'm aware of [Express js render : TypeError: this.engine is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676188/express-js-render-typeerror-this-engine-is-not-a-function) and [Express js render error this.engine is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361109/express-js-render-error-this-engine-is-not-a-function) and [TypeError: this.engine is not a function when trying to use Moustache in Express JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934450/typeerror-this-engine-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-use-moustache-in-express), but they didn't help for me.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @Patrick Roberts concerning reading manuals, I rewrote it and this is how it works:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');

var app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.route('/single/:id')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        res.render('single-poll', {
            id: req.params.id
        });
    });

app.listen(process.env.PORT,  function () {
    console.log('Node.js listening on port ' + process.env.PORT + '...');
});
```

The main thing was, I think, changing the file structure to this:

```
├── app.js
    └── views
        ├── single-poll.handlebars
        └── layouts
            └── main.handlebars
```

Comment: app.engine('handlebars', exphbs.engine({defaultLayout: 'main'}));   

will solve this error .

Answer (score 2):

Since your handlebars template files are saved as `.html`, you should register the engine as `'html'` and not `'handlebars'`:

```
app.engine('html', expressHandlebars({defaultLayout: 'layout', extname: '.html', layoutsDir: 'public/'}));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'public/');

// ...
res.render('single-poll', ...);
```

And your project directory should look like this (I hope):

```
├── app.js
└── public
    ├── layout.html
    └── single-poll.html
```

After finding all the things you needed to change, I really recommend you sit down and [read the ******* manual](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars), because everything I've suggested is right out of there.

Comment: Try removing the file extension from your `res.render()` calls as well. Does that fix it?

Comment: No, it doesn't.